# On lockscreen how can I auto-turn off monitors if they wake up?

Tags: screensaver, screen-lock, dpms

I'm on Debian (Jessie) using KDE 4.14.2 nothing really stood out to me in the System Settings on how to trigger a lock screen and after doing a bunch of research I ended up binding Ctrl+L to run the following command:

```
qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver Lock && xset dpms force off
```

which will trigger the lock screen and turn off my monitors. The prob is if someone bumps into my desk (which is often) the monitors turn on but they don't turn off again.

What can I do to have my monitors automatically turn off after X minutes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for Energy Saving → Screen Energy Saving → "Switch off after". You can get to the Energy Saving settings easily by typing that into the run box or into the search box in the menu.

Comment: I have that set but it doesn't trigger when I use the shortcut to lock the screen. If I don't lock it and leave it it will turn off.